# Time complexity of for loops, I cannot really understand a thing

Tags: time-complexity

So these are the for loops that I have to find the time complexity, but I am not really clearly understood how to calculate.

```
for (int i = n; i > 1; i /= 3) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += 2) {
        ... ...
    }
    for (int k = 2; k < n; k = (k * k) {
        ...
    }
```

For the first line, (int i = n; i > 1; i /= 3), keeps diving i by 3 and if i is less than 1 then the loop stops there, right?

But what is the time complexity of that? I think it is n, but I am not really sure.
The reason why I am thinking it is n is, if I assume that n is 30 then i will be like 30, 10, 3, 1 then the loop stops. It runs n times, doesn't it?

And for the last for loop, I think its time complexity is also n because what it does is

k starts as 2 and keeps multiplying itself to itself until k is greater than n.

So if n is 20, k will be like 2, 4, 16 then stop. It runs n times too.

I don't really think I am understanding this kind of questions because time complexity can be log(n) or n^2 or etc but all I see is n.

I don't really know when it comes to log or square. Or anything else.

Every for loop runs n times, I think. How can log or square be involved?

Can anyone help me understanding this? Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all three loops are independent of each other, we can analyse them separately and multiply the results at the end.

---

**1. `i` loop**

A classic *logarithmic* loop. There are countless examples on SO, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32490177/time-complexity-of-a-loop-that-integer-divides-the-loop-counter-by-a-constant) being a similar one. Using the result given on that page and replacing the division constant:

> The exact number of times that this loop will execute is `ceil(log3(n))`.

**2. `j` loop**

As you correctly figured, this runs `O(n / 2)` times;

> The exact number is `floor(n / 2)`.

**3. `k` loop**

Another classic known result - the *log-log* loop. The code just happens to be an *exact* replicate of [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46554295/time-complexity-of-this-for-loop-for-i-2-i-n-i-i-i) SO post;

> The exact number is `ceil(log2(log2(n)))`

Combining the above steps, the total time complexity is given by

> [image]

Note that the `j`-loop overshadows the `k`-loop.

---

**Numerical tests for confirmation**

JavaScript code:

```
T = function(n) {
  var m = 0;
  for (var i = n; i > 1; i /= 3) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j += 2)
      m++;
    for (var k = 2; k < n; k = k * k)
      m++;
  }
  return m;
}

M = function(n) {
  return ceil(log(n)/log(3)) * (floor(n/2) + ceil(log2(log2(n))));
}
```

`M(n)` is what the math predicts that `T(n)` will exactly be (the number of inner loop executions):

```
n       T(n)    M(n)
-----------------------
100000  550055  550055
105000  577555  577555
110000  605055  605055
115000  632555  632555
120000  660055  660055
125000  687555  687555
130000  715055  715055
135000  742555  742555
140000  770055  770055
145000  797555  797555
150000  825055  825055
```

`M(n)` matches `T(n)` perfectly as expected. A plot of `T(n)` against `n log n` (the predicted time complexity):

[image]

I'd say that is a convincing straight line.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr; I describe a couple of examples first, I analyze the complexity of the stated problem of OP at the bottom of this post**

In short, the big O notation tells you something about how a program is going to perform if you scale the input.

Imagine a program (P0) that counts to 100. No matter how often you run the program, it's going to count to 100 as fast each time (give or take). Obviously right?

Now imagine a program (P1) that counts to a number that is variable, i.e. it takes a number as an input to which it counts. We call this variable `n`. Now each time P1 runs, the performance of P1 is dependent on the size of `n`. If we make `n` a 100, P1 will run very quickly. If we make `n` equal to a googleplex, it's going to take a little longer.

Basically, the performance of P1 is dependent on how big `n` is, and this is what we mean when we say that P1 has time-complexity `O(n)`.

Now imagine a program (P2) where we count to the square root of `n`, rather than to itself. Clearly the performance of P2 is going to be worse than P1, because the number to which they count differs immensely (especially for larger `n`'s (= scaling)). You'll know by intuition that P2's time-complexity is equal to `O(n^2)` if P1's complexity is equal to `O(n)`.

Now consider a program (P3) that looks like this:

```
var length= input.length;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < length; j++) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Product is {input[i] * input[j]}");
    }
}
```

There's no `n` to be found here, but as you might realise, this program still depends on an input called `input` here. Simply because the program depends on some kind of input, we declare this input as `n` if we talk about time-complexity. If a program takes multiple inputs, we simply call those different names so that a time-complexity could be expressed as `O(n * n2 + m * n3)` where this hypothetical program would take 4 inputs.

For P3, we can discover it's time-complexity by first analyzing the number of different inputs, and then by analyzing in what way it's performance depends on the input.

P3 has 3 variables that it's using, called `length`, `i` and `j`. The first line of code does a simple assignment, which' performance is not dependent on any input, meaning the time-complexity of that line of code is equal to `O(1)` meaning constant time.
The second line of code is a `for` loop, implying we're going to do something that might depend on the length of something. And indeed we can tell that this first `for` loop (and everything in it) will be executed `length` times. If we increase the size of `length`, this line of code will do linearly more, thus this line of code's time complexity is `O(length)` (called linear time).

The next line of code will take `O(length)` time again, following the same logic as before, however since we are executing this every time execute the `for` loop around it, the time complexity will be multiplied by it: which results in `O(length) * O(length) = O(length^2)`.

The insides of the second `for` loop do not depend on the size of the input (even though the input is necessary) because indexing on the input (for arrays!!) will not become slower if we increase the size of the input. This means that the insides will be constant time = `O(1)`. Since this runs in side of the other `for` loop, we again have to multiply it to obtain the total time complexity of the nested lines of code: `outside for-loops * current block of code = O(length^2) * O(1) = O(length^2).

The total time-complexity of the program is just the sum of everything we've calculated: `O(1) + O(length^2) = O(length^2) = O(n^2)`. The first line of code was `O(1)` and the `for` loops were analyzed to be `O(length^2)`. You will notice 2 things:

- We rename `length` to `n`: We do this because we express
  time-complexity based on generic parameters and not on the ones that
  happen to live within the program.
- We removed `O(1)` from the equation. We do this because we're only
  interested in the biggest terms (= fastest growing). Since `O(n^2)`
  is way 'bigger' than `O(1)`, the time-complexity is defined equal to
  it (this only works like that for terms (e.g. split by `+`), not for
  factors (e.g. split by `*`).

### OP's problem

Now we can consider your program (P4) which is a little trickier because the variables within the program are defined a little cloudier than the ones in my examples.

```
for (int i = n; i > 1; i /= 3) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += 2) {
        ... ...
    }
    for (int k = 2; k < n; k = (k * k) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If we analyze we can say this:

- The first line of code is executed `O(cbrt(3))` times where `cbrt` is the cubic root of it's input. Since `i` is divided by 3 every loop, the cubic root of `n` is the number of times the loop needs to be executed before `i` is smaller or equal to 1.
- The second `for` loop is linear in time because `j` is executed
  `O(n / 2)` times because it is increased by 2 rather than 1 which
  would be 'normal'. Since we know that `O(n/2) = O(n)`, we can say
  that this for loop is executed `O(cbrt(3)) * O(n) = O(n * cbrt(n))` times (first `for` * the nested `for`).
- The third `for` is also nested in the first `for`, but since it is not nested in the second `for`, we're not going to multiply it by the second one (obviously because it is only executed each time the first `for` is executed). Here, `k` is bound by `n`, however since it is increased by a factor of itself each time, we cannot say it is linear, i.e. it's increase is defined by a variable rather than by a constant. Since we increase `k` by a factor of itself (we square it), it will reach `n` in <sub>`2`</sub>`log(n)` steps. Deducing this is easy if you understand how `log` works, if you don't get this you need to understand that first. In any case, since we analyze that this for loop will be run  `O(`<sub>`2`</sub>`log(n))` time, the total complexity of the third `for` is `O(cbrt(3)) * O(`<sub>`2`</sub>`log(n))` = `O(cbrt(n) *`<sub>`2`</sub>`log(n))`
- The total time-complexity of the program is now calculated by the sum of the different sub-timecomplexities: `O(n * cbrt(n)) + O(cbrt(n) *`<sub>`2`</sub>`log(n))`

As we saw before, we only care about the fastest growing term if we talk about big O notation, so we say that the time-complexity of your program is equal to `O(n * cbrt(n))`.

Comment: "Since i is divided by 3 every loop, the cubic root of n is the number of times the loop needs to be executed" - Non-sequitur. This is a classic example of a *logarithmic* loop. Nor is the third loop simply log2(n).

Comment: Ugh I read this post again and obviously you're right. I shouldn't have posted this after a long day of work. I will take another look at this later, thanks for pointing this out.